# Distinguishing extended blocks of quoted text

Tags: highlighting, quotation

I'm working on a document where I copy large amounts of text from a book by Hartshorne, and interleave it with large amounts of my own text (basically saying "here's what the math book says; here's how we do that with a theorem-prover.") I'd like to distinguish the direct quotations from the math book somehow. An obvious choice is something like "quotation", but they may be multiple pages long, include formatting like sections and subsections, etc., so I was thinking that it'd be nice to just say, at some point, `\begin{hartshorne}` and then, at the end of a quotation, `\end{hartshorne}` and have all the intervening material appear on, say, a pale green background. I'd be equally happy with something like an extended thick green line just to the right of the text (in the margin, say) or some other design choice.

So my question is: Is there a natural way to do something like this in LaTeX? A search for "highlighting" and "background" didn't yield much for me, but my stackexchange search-fu isn't all that strong.

Comment: `tcolorbox` sounds good for such breakable boxes with colored background.

Comment: Have a look at the `mdframed` package. The documentation has lots of pretty examples which might be adaptable: http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf